# /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)

Tags: node.js, shell, aws-code-deploy, lts

When I push the code to Github it automatically builds it and start the application on AWS through CodeDeploy with a application_start.sh script file that has the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

#give permission for everything in the express-app directory
sudo chmod -R 777 /directory/backend

#navigate into our working directory where we have all our files OR exit
cd /directory/backend || exit

#add npm and node to path
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # loads nvm bash_completion 

#install node modules
npm install
npm install pm2@latest -g

#pm2 stop all
pm2 stop backend
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env prodaws
```

[This is the error it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrPzD.png)

127 exit code is "File or Directory Not Found"

I have a nother script that runs before the application_start.sh that installs node, I tried installing a more stable version with `nvm install --lt`  but it did not change anything even the node verison

Comment: I did run:
"nvm use --delete-prefix v19.1.0 --silent" but nothing changed

Comment: That's a pretty common error when you mix an Enterprise Linux with community binaries. You'll need to compile everything yourself, or change your OS.

Comment: I tried to modify the node version but it did not work I believe that some changes need to be in the script files:


this is the before_install.sh file content
#!/bin/bash

#download node and npm
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
#it used to be nvm install node and I changed it to nvm install --lts as written bellow
nvm install --lts

#create our working directory if it doesnt exist
DIR="/directory/backend"
if [ -d "$DIR" ]; then
  echo "${DIR} exists"
else
  echo "Creating ${DIR} directory"
  sudo mkdir ${DIR}
fi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution to this is to change the Operating System, Amazon Linux 2 does not upgrade those libraries to the latest version.
Changing the OS was also suggested by the Amazon Support team check out this [article](https://medium.com/@benmedishak/how-i-went-from-adding-a-single-function-to-a-node-js-56311932730f) where I described in detail what happened.